Dynamic WITH statement
Is it possible to dynamically construct a WITH statement?
I have to do a graph traversal, but I don't know in advance which collections contain the graph nodes. I have tried to create the statement dynamically, but I keep getting strange errors that don't seem to have anything to do with that.
I collect all the collection names from the document handles in the query and I create a comma separated list of collection names that I dynamically inject into the query.
